# How to update UITextView after login

Tags: ios, facebook, uiview

I am trying to integrate Facebook to my iOS app with ARC. To use FB SDK, I have disabled ARC with "-fno-objc-arc" for those files. However, it still have EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and I need to change

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<FBSessionDelegate> sessionDelegate;
```

to

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<FBSessionDelegate> sessionDelegate;
```

The login is working now but the UITextView is not updated after login

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        [delegate facebook].accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [delegate facebook].expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) 
    {
        [[delegate facebook] authorize:nil];
    }
}
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[[delegate facebook] accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[[delegate facebook] expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{    
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) {
        self.uitextview.text = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
}
```

I have checked that "[result objectForKey:@"name"]" will return a result but "self.uitextview" is not recognized.

How do I update a UITextView after successful login?

Comment: where is your `self.uilabel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the ViewController init in Appdelegate can't be used as shown in Facebook Hackbook sample.

Replace with the following declaration:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
ViewController *viewcontroller = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:4];
```

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1